# Ubuntu recovery stuck at DEPEND

Tags: boot

I have Ubuntu 16.04 installed, and I can't reboot the system since it remains stuck indefinitely at the "`5 points loading`".

I entered the Grub and selected recovery mode for checking the problem, and I found it's a network problem. In the recovery mode the system is stuck at the line:

```
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for Network manager wait online.
```